# How can I print something specific in TextView when the condition for EditText input values have been met?

Tags: java, android

So I am a begginer & I made a simple CGPA calculator. Everything is working great but I wanna add grades in TextView when each EditText gets a value. So I want to add one or multiple condition to display grades in `tv` textview when `show_grades` button is pressed. **For Instance** if user inputs **4.00**, then I want to print grade ***A+*** in `tv` textview.
As you can see, I have added a simple if statement, but I hade to make 4 individual if statement just to display a single grade in 2 fields. If I want to do it for 8 fields and 12 grades(like A+, A, A-, B+, B, B-....) I have to make 96 statements. Is there a better way to do so.

```java
///import & stuffs
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText S1, S2;
    TextView tv, tv2;
    Button show_grade, resetButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        S1 =  findViewById(R.id.S1);//edittext assigning section
        S2 =  findViewById(R.id.S2);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);

        show_grade =  findViewById(R.id.show_grade);//button assigning section
        resetButton = findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

       
        show_grade.setOnClickListener(view -> {

          double s1 = Double.parseDouble(S1.getText().toString());
            double s2 = Double.parseDouble(S2.getText().toString());
            double g1 = 4.00, g2 =3.50;
            if(s1==g1 ){
                tv.setText("A+");
            }
            if(s1==g2 ){
                tv.setText("A-");
            }
             if(s2==g1 ){
                tv2.setText("A+");
            }
             if(s2==g2 ) {
                 tv2.setText("A-");
             }
        });
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(view -> { //executing reset function
            S1.setText("");
            S2.setText("");
        });
    }
}
```

And here is activity's layout for 1 EditText & Textview only

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/S1"
            android:layout_width="130sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="creditCardNumber"
            android:ems="10"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/S1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:background="@color/color1"
            android:hint="Grades"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimary2" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/S2"
            android:layout_width="130sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="creditCardNumber"
            android:ems="10"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/S1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:background="@color/color1"
            android:hint="Grades"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimary2" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/show_grade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Show grade"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: didnt get what is the objective can you explain what do you mean by "if input value double a is between double x & y then print double z in TextView" or you are unable to setText in textview getting error ?

Comment: As I said it is a cgpa calculator app & the objective is to show grades in the Textview when the user inputs a value in EditText. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

OK. if you want to setText on some event like button click than

```
TextView tvText;
EditText editText;

button.setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        String str = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        tvText.setText(str);
    }
     }
 );
```

But, if you want textview to show/update value as per change in EditText without
an event than use TextWatcher():

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        String inputText;
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit)
        {
            inputText = mEdit.toString();
            tvText.setText(inputText);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int 
             after)
        {

   
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
         count){

        }
    });
```

In your code change

```
tv.setText("Your CGPA is:   " + ans);
```

to

```
tv.setText("Your CGPA is:   " + String.valueOf(ans));
```

TextView accepts String only

Comment: I guess I was terrible at explaining my problem. So I added some if statement and simplified my code focusing in my objective. So, please read through my question again. I wish my question is more understandable this time